# Haskell pattern match error with bind operator

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, bind

I have a task, where I am stuck at a point, where I do not get any further.
Given is a function:

```
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose []       =  []
transpose ([]:ls)  =  transpose ls
transpose ll       =  [h | (h:_) <- ll] : transpose [t |(_:t) <- ll]
```

I shall write it again using the do-notation on the one hand and the bind-operator on the other hand. I may use hd, tl and (:).
I do not have problems with the do-notation solution but there is a pattern matching problem with the bind version.
Here is, what I have so far:

```
transheadA ll = ll >>= \(h:_) ->
    return h

transtailA ll = ll >>= \(_:t) ->
    return t

transposeA :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transposeA []       =  []
transposeA ([]:ls)  =  transposeA ls
transposeA ll       =  (transheadA ll : transposeA (transtailA ll))
```

The same style for the do-notation works but with the bind operator I get a pattern match error at transheadA with

```
\(h:_) -> ...
```

See:

```
transposeA [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6*** Exception: transpose.hs:(16,22)-(17,24): Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
```

I was thinking about how to solve this problem a longer time but I do not know, where to add a new pattern to let this work.

## EDIT

I just want hints, of course.
Direct solutions are not the sense of the homework nor of this board.
Thank You

## EDIT SOLUTION

Thanks to CommuSoft I could solve this problem, I think.
My solution now is the following:

```
transheadA :: [[a]] -> [a]
transheadA ll = ll >>= f
    where f (h:_) = return h
          f _     = fail []


transtailA :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transtailA ll = ll >>= f
    where f (_:t) = return t
          f _     = fail []

transposeA :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transposeA []       =  []
transposeA ([]:ls)  =  transposeA ls
transposeA ll       =  (transheadA ll : transposeA (transtailA ll))
```

Comment: what is the expected behavior when one argument is shorter than the others? Did you intend the input to be `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` ? Or maybe just a typo?

Comment: The problem is that it is not certain that all the elements in a list have a head, the empty array `[]` for instance hasn't. `<-` does more than simply matching, it filters as well.

Comment: The input is right the way it is. The list shorter than the others shall be left out, simply not taken in the result. Better said when there are no more elements to take into the resulting listlist, then the empty list shall be appended, or better, nothing to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with this approach:

- The signature of `transheadA` should be different than the one for `transtailA`.

  ```
  transheadA :: [[a]] -> [a]
  transtailA :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
  ```
- Since you do some pattern matching in the list comprehension, you cannot simply use this in the lambda expression: it is possible the pattern fails in which case that part of the list comprehension `fail`s as well. You can inline this as:

  ```
  where f (h:_) = return h
        f _ = fail []
  ```

  Then you can use `f` in the side of the binding operator `>>=`. Clearly this has an impact on how to encode things. Implicitly for each such pattern matching (thus everything not `x <-` with `x` a single variable) Haskell could have written such `fail` (be aware Haskell does not necessarily uses the list monad).
- As you can read [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) for the list monad, you don't need to use `return`, although in this context it not much of a problem, but will reduce the length of your code. In that case you need to replace the right hand side of the expression with `[x]` instead of `x`.

Based on the above hints, I've managed to fix your implementation of `transpose` myself. I hope this clarifies a thing or two?